# Open Linux terminal command in PHP

Tags: php, linux

I have a server running on Linux that execute commands to 12 nodes (12 computers with Linux running in them). I recently downloaded PHP on the server to create web pages that can execute commands by opening a specific PHP file.

I used `exec()`, `passthru()`, `shell_​exec()`, and `system()`. `system()` is the only one that returns a part of my code. I would like PHP to act like open termainal command in linux and I cannot figure out how to do it!

Here is an example of what is happening now (Linux directly vs PHP):
When using linux open terminal command directly:

```
user@wizard:/home/hyperwall/Desktop> /usr/local/bin/chbg -mt
```

I get an output:

```
The following settings will be used:
  option = mtsu   COLOR =    IMAGE = imagehereyouknow!
  NODES  = LOCAL
and additional code to send it to 12 nodes.
```

Now with PHP:

```
switch($_REQUEST['do'])
{ case 'test':
    echo system('/usr/local/bin/chbg -mt');
    break;
}
```

Output:

```
The following settings will be used:
  option = mtsu   COLOR =    IMAGE = imagehereyouknow!
  NODES  = LOCAL
```

And stops! Anyone has an explanation of what is happening? And how to fix it? Only system displays part of the code the other functions display nothing!

Comment: Have you used `strace` to figure out what it's stuck on? Run the web server in debug mode to restrict it to a single process.

Comment: Which web server are you running? Under which user is the webserver running? If it runs under "nobody" or similar, are you sure that user can execute the chbg command ?

Comment: what is "and additional code to send it to 12 nodes." ?? where is it comming from ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My First thought is it can be something about std and output error. Some softwares dump some informations on std out and some in std error. When you are not redirecting std error to std out, most of the system calls only returns the stdout part. It sounds thats why you see the whole output in terminal and can't in the system calls.
So try with

```
 /usr/local/bin/chbg -mt 2>&1
```

**Edit:**
Also for a temporary work through, you can try some other things. For example redirect the output to file next to the script and read its contents after executing the command, This way you can use the exec:

```
exec("usr/local/bin/chbg -mt 2>&1 > chbg_out");
//Then start reading chbg_out and see is it work
```

**Edit2**
Also it does not make sense why others not working for you.
For example this piece of code written in c, dumps a string in stderr and there is other in stdout.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{

    fputs("\nerr\nrro\nrrr\n",stderr);
    fputs("\nou\nuu\nuttt\n",stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

and this php script, tries to run that via exec:

```
<?php

exec("/tmp/ctest",&$result);

foreach ( $result as $v )
{
echo $v;
}
#output ouuuuttt
?>
```

See it still dumps out the stdout. But it did not receive the stderr.
Now consider this:

```
<?php

exec("/tmp/ctest 2>&1",&$result);

foreach ( $result as $v )
{
    echo $v;
}
//output: errrrorrrouuuuttt
?>
```

See, this time we got the whole outputs.

This time the system:

```
<?php
     echo system("/tmp/ctest 2>&1");
     //output: err rro rrr ou uu uttt uttt
?>
```

and so on ...

Comment: Great answer, well backed up with examples.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your chbg -mt writes additional code to stderr instead of stdout? Try to execute your script inside php like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/chbg -mt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

The other responses are good for generic advice. But in this specific case, it appears you are trying to change your background on your desktop. This requires many special considerations because of 'user context':

- First, your web server is probably running as a different user, and therefore would not have permissions to change your desktop.
- Second, the program probably requires some environmental variables from your user context. For example, X programs need a `DISPLAY` variable,  ssh-agent needs `SSH_AGENT_PID` and `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, etc. I don't know much about changing backgrounds, but I'm guessing it involves D-Bus, which probably requires things like  `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`, `KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE`, `KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION`, and `KONSOLE_DBUS_WINDOW`. There may be many others.  Note that some of these vars change every time you log in, so you can't hard-code them on the PHP side.

For testing, it might be simpler to start your own webserver right from your user session. (i.e. Don't use the system one, it has to run as you. You will need to run it on an alternate port, like 8080). The web server you start manually will have all the 'context' it needs.  I'll mention [websocketd](http://websocketd.com/) because it just came out and looks neat.

For "production", you may need to run a daemon in your user context all the time, and have the web server talk to that daemon to 'get stuff done' inside your user context.

Comment: To me, the "desktop" issue is irrelevant as it's assumed and could just be part of the example question. The real question is about why there are inconsistencies between Linux command line and PHP executed Linux commands. I think your first point about the fact that PHP is being run by a different user to what you'd normally use in the Linux console is the most prudent and important point to raise. For the sake of consistency it might pay to be running your Linux commands as the user that runs PHP to further emulate the behaviour of PHP's system calls

Answer (score 2):

PHP's [`system`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) only returns the last line of execution:

> Return Value: Returns the last line of the command output on success, and FALSE on failure.

You will most likely want to use either `exec` or `passthru`. `exec` has an optional parameter to put the output into an array. You could implode the output and use that to echo it.

```
switch($_REQUEST['do'])
{ case 'test':
    exec('/usr/local/bin/chbg -mt', $output);
    echo implode('\n', $output); // Could use <br /> if HTML output is desired
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the result of execution, can changes between users.
First, try to run your PHP script directly into your terminal `php yourScript.php`

If it runs as expected, go to your Apache service and update it to run with your own credentials

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change the backgrounds for currently logged in users... While they are using the desktop.  Like while I'm typing this message.  I minimize my browser and 'ooh my desktop background is different'.   Hopefully this is for something important like it turns red when the reactor or overheating.

Anyway to my answer:

Instead of trying to remotely connect and run items as the individual users.  Setup each user to run a bash script (in their own account, in their own shell) on a repeating timer.  Say every 10 minutes.  Have it select the SAME file.. from a network location
/somenetworkshare/backgrounds/images/current.png

Then you can update ALL nodes (1 to a million) just by changing the image itself in /somenetworkshare/backgrounds/images/current.png

Comment: The downside of the "many requesting from one" approach is that you introduce 1 to a million times the processing time required and decrease your overall performance at a guaranteed rate, whereas the "one to many push" approach only degrades when required.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something a while ago that does just this -- you can run a command interpreter (/bin/sh), send it commands, read back responses, send more commands, etc.  It uses `proc_open()` to open a child process and talk to it.

It's at http://github.com/andrasq/quicklib, Quick/Proc/Process.php

Using it would look something like (easier if you have a flexible autoloader; I wrote one of those too in Quicklib):

```
include 'lib/Quick/Proc/Exception.php';
include 'lib/Quick/Proc/Exists.php';
include 'lib/Quick/Proc/Process.php';

$proc = new Quick_Proc_Process("/bin/sh");
$proc->putInput("pwd\n");
$lines = $proc->getOutputLines($nlines = 10, $timeoutSec = 0.2);
echo $lines[0];
$proc->putInput("date\n");
$lines = $proc->getOutputLines(1, 0.2);
echo $lines[0];
```

Outputs

```
/home/andras/quicklib
Sat Feb 21 01:50:39 EST 2015
```

The unit of communication between php and the process is newline terminated lines.  All commands must be newline terminated, and all responses are retrieved in units of lines.  Don't forget the newlines, they're hard to identify afterward.

Comment: This comes across as more of an advertisement for a script you've worked on than an answer to the question

Comment: yeah, I replied to "I would like PHP to act like open termainal command in linux" without scrolling down to read the rest in detail.  I thought it would be helpful; didn't realize that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project that uses Terminal A on machine A to output to Terminal B on Machine B, both using linux for now. I didnt see it mentioned, but perhaps you can use redirection, something like this in your webserver:

```
switch($_REQUEST['do'])
 { case 'test':
    #process ID on the target (12345, 12346 etc)
    echo system('/usr/local/bin/chbg -mt > /proc/<processID>/fd/1'); 
    #OR
    #device file on the target (pts/0,tty0, etc) 
    echo system('/usr/local/bin/chbg -mt > /dev/<TTY-TYPE>/<TTYNUM>');
    break;
 }
```

Definitely the permissions need to be set correctly for this to work. The command "mesg y" in a terminal may also assist...Hope that helps.